# C# Designer cannot process code

Tags: c#

```
List<string> devices = new List<string>();
        devices.Add("Register 1");
        devices.Add("Register 2");
        devices.Add("AIO 1");


        TreeNode[] registers = new TreeNode[2];
        TreeNode[] AIOs = new TreeNode[1];

        int r = 0;
        int a = 0;
        foreach (string name in devices)
        {
            if (name.Contains("Register"))
            {
                registers[r] = new TreeNode("Register " + (r + 1));
                registers[r].Name = "Register " + (r + 1);
                registers[r].Text = "Register " + (r + 1);
                r++;
            } if (name.Contains("AIO"))
            {
                AIOs[a] = new TreeNode("AIO " + (a + 1));
                AIOs[a].Name = "AIO " + (a + 1);
                AIOs[a].Text = "AIO " + (a + 1);
                a++;
            }
        }
        System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode treeNode1 = new          System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode("Controller");
        System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode treeNode6 = new  System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode("Registers", registers);
        System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode treeNode9 = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode("AIOs", AIOs);
        System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode treeNode10 = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode("Router");
        System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode treeNode11 = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode("Store");
```

This is the pertinent code. I changed the form1.designer class so that based on a list of items it will generate them and add them to a list. It says I cant modify the designer, any way around this?

Edit : Ok so dont edit form 1. But lets say I want to base the tree off of how many registers or aios there are, and that number can vary. How could I make it so that form 1 is able to create a different number of trees each time?

Comment: "I changed the form1.designer class" - Don't!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If your tree needs to be loaded dynamically from a data source, you should do this in the form load event instead of changing directly from designer class.

Or, if the tree is never change, you can use the Nodes property on the designer's Properties toolbox to add the nodes there.

Changing codes from Designer class is never a good practice as the changes will be lost if you do anything with the form in the Form Designer screen